# Android JNI C simple append function

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Id like to make a simple function, that return value of two Strings, basically:

java

```
public native String getAppendedString(String name);
```

c

```
jstring Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_getAppendedString(JNIEnv* env,   jobject thiz, jstring s) {
    jstring sx = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, s, NULL);

    return ((*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "asd ")+sx);
}
```

It returns:

```
jni/hello-jni.c:32: warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type
jni/hello-jni.c:34: error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'char *' and 'char *')
```

The retval will be: "asd qwer", how can I do this?

```
jstring s1  = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "456");
jstring s2  = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "123");
jstring sall=strcat(s1, s2);

return sall;
```

Only returns "456"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1. `GetStringUTFChars` returns a `jbyte *` (a null-terminated C string), not a `jstring`.  You need this C string to do string manipulation in C.
2. You need to call `ReleaseStringUTFChars` when you're done with it.
3. You need to allocate enough memory to hold the concatenated string, using `malloc`.
4. As ethan mentioned, you need to concatenate your two C strings with `strcat`.  (You cannot do this with the `+` operator.  When applied to a pointer, `+` returns the pointer from the offset of the original pointer.)
5. Remember to free the memory you allocated after you're done with it (ie, after it's been interned as a Java string.)

You should do something along the lines of:

```
char *concatenated;
const jbyte *sx;
jstring retval;

/* Get the UTF-8 characters that represent our java string */
sx = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, s, NULL);

/* Concatenate the two strings. */
concatenated = malloc(strlen("asd ") + strlen(sx) + 1);
strcpy(concatenated, "asd ");
strcat(concatenated, sx);

/* Create java string from our concatenated C string */
retval = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, concatenated);

/* Free the memory in sx */
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, s, sx);

/* Free the memory in concatenated */
free(concatenated);

return retval;
```

Comment: this code not working, its give me a lot of error in the Logcat, and just force closing without "forse close" message.

Comment: please see my new edited code, is it all right? all the releases are  good?

Comment: Well, only accidentally.  You need to allocate enough memory for `strcat`, you can't simply pass in `s1x`.  You need to follow the pattern above.  That is, `char *sall = malloc(strlen(s1x) + strlen(s2x) + 1); strcpy(sall, s1x); strcat(sall, s2x);`

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate two `char*` with `+` in c++. Try using `strcat` instead.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/

EDIT:

from the documentation for strcat:

> char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
>
> Concatenate strings
>
> Appends a copy of the source string to the destination string. The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first character of source, and a new null-character is appended at the end of the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.

This means that the first argument to strcat needs to have enough memory allocated to fit the entire concatenated string.

Comment: sorry but all are jstrings, not char*

Comment: based on the compiler error they are both char*'s in disguise [typedef]'s

Comment: The + operator also doesn't work with jstring's, which as SSpoke pointed out, are basically char*. I'd still suggest using strcat to concatenate the two strings.