# What may be the easiest way to append multiple jstrings in JNI?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I'm working on an android app where I need to append 5-6 jstrings and want to return a single jstring in native code. Strings are like...

```
jstring1= "Hello, "
jstring2= "How"
jstring3= "are"
jstring4= "you"
jstring5= "today?"
```

and I want to return a jstring like, "Hello, how are you today?" I'm Just wandering to know the easiest way to do it.

Comment: If the native side is not doing anything useful with the strings, just use a StringBuilder.

Comment: Yes sir, I'm totally agree with your answer but it is for a purpose that's to be used inside the Native Code.

Comment: This looks like it does almost what you are after - the only difference is they have one jstring and one C string and you have more than one jstring but the method is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8302259/2193968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you make a `StringBuilder`:

```
jclass cls_StringBuilder = env->FindClass("java/lang/StringBuilder");
jmethodID ctr_StringBuilder = env->GetMethodID(cls_StringBuilder, "<init>", "(I)V");
jobject stringBuilder = env->NewObject(cls_StringBuilder, ctr_StringBuilder, 100);
```

And then you append string by string:

```
jmethodID mid_StringBuilder_append = env->GetMethodID(cls_StringBuilder, "append", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;");
for (auto str: { jstring1, jstring2, jstring3, jstring4, jstring5 }) {
  env->CallObjectMethod(stringBuilder, mid_StringBuilder_append, str);
}
```

Finally grab the contents of the StringBuilder:

```
jmethodID mid_StringBuilder_toString = env->GetMethodID(cls_StringBuilder, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring final = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(stringBuilder, mid_StringBuilder_toString);
return final;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It also gave me idea regarding the solution of other things too.

Comment: it is giving an error in <init> as Method name not found in class StringBuilder.

Comment: That constructor should always be present (since Java 1.5) .. but you can try with the no-argument constructor, I guess. Use "()V" as signature and don't pass the last argument to NewObject

Comment: I just tried for myself using Android studio and it just compiled.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your IDE with the code and the error?

Comment: Yes sir, I also got it working. Actually, it is only showing the warning in red but when I compiled, it worked successfully. Thanks for your help. :)